# which data structure should be used for storing different tag values of XML after parsing it

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I want to know a data structure for storing values of tags. My XML structure is :

```
<personaldetails>
    <name>Michael</name>
    <age>28</age>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <address>123 Streeet 7</address>
    <country>India</country>
    <pincode> 1234877</pincode>
    <contactno>35646445</contactno>
    <emailid>michael@abc.com</emailid>
</personaldetails>
```

I want to store the values at a single place using data structure.Presently i am using setter and getter methods for retrieving values which is making my code large.
Can someone suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters and setters on an object have the advantage of type safety. For example if you tried to write the code `getContactN` then the compiler would give you an error. So although it might make your code long, getters and setters are good.

An alternative would be to use a map e.g. `Map<String,String>` to store the values. This is more general - you can insert whatever key you like - and is less code, however it doesn't give you the static analysis benefits of getters and setters. If you mis-spell something you will only discover it when you execute that bit of code - and if it's in an `if` the code might not always get executed and you might miss it.

There would also be performance differences between using getters/setters and a map, however, i imagine in 99% of applications they would be irrelevant so it's not worth pointing out here. If that code becomes a bottleneck you could put timings in to see which approach is better - but do that only if you can verify you have performance problems in this area, otherwise just use whichever technique is more maintainable and easier for you.

Comment: Thanx a lot Adrian....But my XML is way too long and making getter setter for each tag is quite large though Easy!!!! I want to use Maps but I am not sure as of now whether code will have if conditions or not

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you avoid reinventing the wheel by writing your own "container" classes.  Instead you could consider generating your Java classes directly from your XML schema using a tool such as xjc, which ships with the JDK.  There is a massive advantage in this approach - You do not have to concern yourself with any explicit parsing of XML and the JAXB code will also validate your XML content.

More info on using JAXB [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing.html).

**EDIT**: I only just spotted the Android tag and I confess I'm not sure whether the javax.xml.bind package ships with the JDK for Android devices.  However, googling for "xml binding android" seemed to bring up a number of third party tools you could consider.